# add new option to select drop down list using jsp

Tags: javascript, html, database, jsp, drop-down-menu

can anyone please suggest , how to add new option to drop down list (using select tag in html) so that user can enter the new value and on submit it should be appended to the existing list ..i am able to populate it's option list via DB dynamically and it's working properly

i am having 5 drop down mutually exclusive category lists in a single table row and i am providing them some initial options.Now i want that if the list contains user's required option then user can select from existing one ...else it should be able to add a new entry to that list & it should be simultaneously updated in DB on submit.

Comment: hiii,
finally it's done.
i used following function as-

function abc()
{
    var myoption = document.createElement("option"); //works with both mozilla and IE
    myoption.text ="mytext";
    myoption.id="mytext";
    myoption.name="mytext";
    myoption.value ="mytext"; //Probably, the sID stuff

    document.getElementById("drop_1").options.add(myoption);
}

& so on within loop. 
thanks to all .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow this steps**

1. As you are populating the drop down from databse . So its better to add the value in database only.
2. I think your user will be entering the value in a text box. So on submit call a method or servlet which can be used to add the value in the database field from which you are populating the drop down.
3. After updation make your servlet to return on the same page.
4. Now you can see your new option in the drop down.

**Update on further problem explaination**

For your problem do one thing

1. Give a text box in last option of each dropdown.
2. Select an event in which after the new value entered by user in that text box an java script function can be triggered line onmouseout.
3. In that function call get the text value .
4. Now call your servlet or method or whatever you are using to update the db with value value in the column corresponding to that drop down using Ajax or normally.
5. Refresh the page.

Comment: i am having 5 drop down mutually exclusive category lists in a single table row and i am providing them some initial options.Now i want that if the list contains user's required option then user can select from existing one ...else it should be able to add a new entry to that list & it should be simultaneously updated in DB on submit.

Comment: @Okk Woner_boy_111 wait its my lunchtime. I will get back to you in just few mins

Comment: @Kk Apply this strategy and get back to me if you are getting any problem any where.

Comment: @Wonder_boy_111 is it done if you have any problem in doing that ask here to me so that everyone searching on this portal can get the benefit of our discussion.

Comment: @Nikhil...no it's not working !!!
even text box are not being displayed at the end of list

Comment: @Wonder_boy_111 is it necessary for you to keep that textbox inside of drop.

Comment: -no it's not...but anyhow i need to provide the facility that- if user's choice is not listed then he should be able to enter it's own new one

Comment: @Wonder_boy_111 Very good please share your solution to everybody answer your own question so that everybody can get the benefit of it. Can I have ur mail id.

Comment: @Nikhil- my mail id-

abhi.saxena111@gmail.com

thanks for your support

Comment: @Wonder_boy_111 everytime there for help my mail id is nikhilagrawal60@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1):

hiii,
finally it's done.
i used following function as-

```
function abc()
{
    var myoption = document.createElement("option"); //works with both mozilla and IE
    myoption.text ="mytext";
    myoption.id="mytext";
    myoption.name="mytext";
    myoption.value ="mytext"; //Probably, the sID stuff

    document.getElementById("drop_1").options.add(myoption);
}
```

& so on within loop. 
thanks to all .